# how to bind a viewmodel containing a list and parameters to a controller action from cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, view

I have a viewModel containing a list and another class like so :

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<Guids> Ids{ get; set; }

    public History HistoryRecord{ get; set; }
}

public class History
{
    public string UserName{ get; set; }
    public string Email{ get; set; }

}
```

and a controller action that I need to send the above data to:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> myAction([Bind("Ids","UserName","Email")] MyViewModel viewModel)
{
... 
    
}
```

i'm getting the values for userName and Email via inputs

```
                        <input type="text" class="form-control child " name="name" id="nameTextbox" placeholder="name" required />
                        <input type="text" class="form-control child " name="email" id="emailTextbox" placeholder="email" required />
```

how can I send this from a razor page?

i've tried using url.Action but this doesnt seem to work and not sure how to put multiple values in

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="confirm" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("myAction","myController", values: new {Ids= @Model.Ids.ToList(), Name = ? , Emil = ? })'">confrim</button>
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding an Id field in your History model and just using a List<History> for your controller/view. Then you'll need to add some javascript to your view checkout this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66031714/form-for-a-model-that-contains-a-list-property-in-asp-net-core-3-mvc)

Comment: Hi,is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add hidden inputs to the form,It looks like you want to use `List<Guid> Ids`,here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<Guid> Ids{ get; set; }

    public History HistoryRecord{ get; set; }
}
```

add following data to the form:

```
@for(var i=0;i<Model.Ids.Count;i++)
{
    <input asp-for="@Model.Ids[i]" hidden />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For binding values from Razor View to action you can use the asp-for tag helper.
In your example:

```
<input asp-for="UserName" type="text" class="form-control child " name="name" id="nameTextbox" placeholder="name" required />

<input asp-for="Email" type="text" class="form-control child " name="email" id="emailTextbox" placeholder="email" required />
```

Your button code replace with:

```
<input type="submit" value="confrim" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

Don't forget to put this code into form tag and set [HttpPost] attribute for action

Final Razor View be like:

```
@model MyViewModel
<form asp-action="myAction" method="post">
    <input asp-for="@Model.Ids[i]" class="form-control child " required />
    <input asp-for="@Model.UserName" type="text" class="form-control child " name="name" id="nameTextbox" placeholder="name" required />
    <input asp-for="@Model.Email" type="text" class="form-control child " name="email" id="emailTextbox" placeholder="email" required />
    
    <input type="submit" value="confrim" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

More information on [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-input-tag-helper).